# How to test 3D on Windows? Or where's DirectX's dxsetup?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, 3d-graphics

When I used Windows 98 I used to type "dxsetup" in "Start->Run..." and it runs some tests of the DirectX.

Now, with DirectX 9 on my Windows XP there's no dxsetup. Where it is? Or, is there another tool to test my card for 3D?

Comment: Are you looking for dxdiag?

Comment: @James may be, but it also don't exist here..

Comment: sure it does.  Just type in dxdiag in the run box.  If it isn't there, something is wrong with your install.

Comment: @Tofystedeth I thought it was wrong, but there were no error messages on the installation.. Anyway, I'll reinstall it..

Comment: something must be wrong, becouse it's not even on the add/remove menu.. but, also, I can't reinstall it becouse "it is already intalled"..

Comment: So do you not have dxdiag.exe in C:\Windows\System32?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably used some modded XP installation media. dxdiag is installed by default in XP and usualy there is no way to skip it during installation or remove it using "Add/Remove Windows components".

You can get this file from original CD (just look for  or DXDIAG.EX_ in I368 folder).

Rename this DXDIAG.EX_ into DXDIAG.CAB and unpack it just like usual CAB archive.